# What is the syntax for an external CSS file when adding to VF page

Tags: visualforce

All I am trying to do is add a background image to my visualforce page with CSS. Here is what I have, very simple just not sure if I am missing something small because it is not working.

this is what mystyles.css contains

```
style type="text/css"
body { background-image: url("/Image/SBbg.jpg") }   
style
```

I know the <> need to be added but anything else wrong with that?

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 2):

Unless the image is available at some public URL and you are happy to use it from there, it is best to [add it as a static resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce) to your project. You can then reference it in your page by whatever name you choose like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url("{! $Resource.ImageName }") !important
}
</style>
```

Note that without the (somewhat hacky) `!important` the platform's default background image settings will apply and you will not see your image.

The body of the page starts in the the top left hand corner where there is usually a header with e.g. global search in it. If you only want this image applied to the normal page content area (below the heading and to the right of the side bar) then you should specify a class name instead of the body element and apply that class to the relevant part of your page.

**PS**

Taking the image from a ZIP static resource and using a CSS class name:

```
<style type="text/css">
.myclassname {
    background-image: url("{! URLFOR($Resource.ZipName, 'Image/SBbg.jpg') }")
}
</style>

...

<apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="myclassname">
    ...
</apex:outputPanel>
```

or just in plain HTML tags:

```
<div class="myclassname">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Nice thank you. How would I do that(specify a classname)? Sorry just started working with CSS yesterday haha. Yeah I had been using it as a static resource. I had the SBbg.jpg in an Image folder and that was zipped up with the mystyles.css file. Seems to be a ton of different ways to reference the static resource from a visualforce page.

Comment: @marco634 See the "PS". Really there are only two forms of static resource: 1) where the file is the static resource; 2) where the file is in a folder in a ZIP that is the static resource...

Comment: Awesome! Much appreciated that was going to drive me nuts. Thanks again for your time and help